# Quick Look: How to return to unindexed view using mouse

Tags: macos, quicklook

After selecting some images and pressing ≪Spacebar≫, I click on the index button: [image: Grid button]

This is what I see:

[image]

Without the keyboard (Ctrl-Enter), how do I get back to the unindexed view?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On 10.13.2 a **single click** on any image returns to Quick Look on just that image, as hover on any image highlights with a blue rectangle.

Answer (score 1):

Testing it on 10.13 it seems you have to **double click** on the image you want to return to the full size preview of.